# Strlen error in c

Tags: c, strlen

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
char* matrix [10][10];  
int main(void){         
        int i;
          char* list[4];
         char words[20][20]={" c a t "," c a r "," b e a r "," s h i p "," m o u s e "," b e a t l e "," c o a t "," n e s t "," i c e "," s u g a r "," b a c o n "," f r o w n "," s m i l e "," d e a d "," f e a t h e r "," g o a t "," h e n "," j e l l y "," k o a l a "," l i p s "};

        int length=0;
        int num;
        int k;
        int m;
        char otherString=0;
        char c;
        int j;
        int s;
        int r;


        char test[10];
        char* token;

const char *search = " ";
        char* empty="";
        int size;
        int ans;

        int x;
        int y;
        int pos;
        int pos2;
        int randRow;
        int randColumn;
        int chosen[10];
        int random;
        int d;
        int ROWS      = 10;      // number of rows
 int COLUMNS   = 10;      // number of columns




        printf("\tA\tB\tC\tD\tE\tF\tG\tH\tI\tJ\n");


        srand(time(NULL));


            for(r=0;r<10;r++){

            for(s=0;s<10;s++){
srand(time(NULL));

            c='1';  


        memset(matrix,c,sizeof(matrix));        
            }}


        for( i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf( "\n%d",i );
    d=0;
        do{
            random = (rand()%20);
            list[i]=words[random];
            d=0;
            for( j=0;j<i;j++){
                if(strcmp(words[random],list[j])==0)d=1;
            }
        }while(d);


    printf("%s",words[random]);
    token = strtok((words[random]),search); 
    printf("%s",token);
    while(token!=NULL) 
   {
      printf("\nrand%d",random);
      length=strlen(words[(random)]);
     printf("len is:%d",length);
      matrix [i][0]=token;
          for( k=1;k<=length;k++){
          token = strtok(NULL, search); 
        printf("%s",token);

            matrix [i][k]=token;

      } 
    } }


            for(r=0;r<10;r++){
            printf("\n");   
            for(s=0;s<10;s++){




                 printf("\t%c",matrix[r][s]);


            }}


        getchar();
            return 0;
            }
```

> since chars are seperated by space the strlen marks the rest as
>
> > garbage . so answer is always 2. any ideas how to fix?? length is
> >     always 2.
> >         maybe it asumes spaces mean end of string ??
> >         not sure how to fix

Comment: The `strlen` function looks for the terminating null-character `'\0'`, it doesn't care about spaces.

Comment: How are you displaying/using `length`?  Are you also displaying the selected word to verify that you're calling `strlen` on a valid string?  Did you include `string.h`?  It would help to see a bit more context.

Comment: Your conclusion is not correct and your claimed result does not make sense. Please provide a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see exactly what you are printing and so that we can reproduce your results.

Comment: Your code formatting/indentation is ... unusual.

Comment: why? something wrong with my code ?

Comment: Unrelated to the question title: do not call `srand()` more than once in your program.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you tell it otherwise, the `rand()` function is automatically seeded with a value of 1. That's why you get the same answer every time.

Fix with an appropriate call to `srand`, perhaps based on your system clock time.

`strlen` does not discard spaces, but returns when the first `\0` is reached.

Comment: Even with the same rand() value each time, I don't see any of the elements in that array that would give the length 2 ?

Comment: Unless OP is printing `random` instead of `length`. That would be my guess. But can't tell with the way that question is currently written.

Comment: I just ran a quick test by copy-pasting OPs code into an empty project, and outputting the value of length and words[random]. It accurately gave the length of the word, but as this answer correctly stated, it will always give the same answer due to seeding. In my case random had the value of 2, which gave the answer " c a r ", which was length 7. Upvoting this answer

Comment: i am printing length,

Comment: when printing length for example "feather" strlen gives 2 and with string" beatle" strlen gives 2 aswell

Comment: @chris could you edit your OP to show the code you're using to print length ? As well as any other relevant code ? You will always get the same word at the moment due to the `rand` function producing the same value. As stated in my comment, using the exact code in your OP and adding `std::cout<<length<<std::endl;` gave me `7` each time, as `rand()` would always produce `1` without a seed, this would always pick ` c a r ` as the word, and correctly give me the length of it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

```
token = strtok((words[random]),search);
```

`strtok` modifies its argument by replacing the delimiter with the 0 terminator; after the first call to `strtok`, `" c a t "` becomes `" c"`, which has a length of 2.

You'll need to perform the `strtok` call on a *copy* of `words[random]`, like so:

```
char temp[20];
strcpy( temp, words[random] );
...
token = strtok( temp, search );
```

**Edit**

Not to be unduly harsh, but ... your code's a *mess*.  I'm not sure what it is you're trying to accomplish, but you have a ton of unused variables, several type mismatches, your output is confusing and unreadable, etc.  The poor formatting makes the code hard to understand and follow; just making the indentation consistent exposed a couple of issues (such as a redundant `srand` call).  gcc threw up a bunch of warnings about the unused variables, as well as missing declarations for `srand` and `rand`.

I've taken your code and pared it way down to focus on the `strtok` and `strlen` issue, and reformatted both the code and the output to make it somewhat readable.  Here's the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  char words[20][20]={" c a t ",       " c a r ",     " b e a r ",   " s h i p ",   " m o u s e ",
                      " b e a t l e ", " c o a t ",   " n e s t ",   " i c e ",     " s u g a r ",
                      " b a c o n ",   " f r o w n ", " s m i l e ", " d e a d ",   " f e a t h e r ",
                      " g o a t ",     " h e n ",     " j e l l y ", " k o a l a ", " l i p s "};

  char* token;

  const char *search = " ";
  int random;

  srand(time(NULL));

  for( i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    printf( "%d: ",i );
    random = rand() % 20;
    const char *blanks="                   ";
    printf("%.*s\"%s\", len is %2zu: token list:  ",(int) (strlen( blanks ) - (strlen(words[random]))),
                                                    blanks, words[random], strlen( words[random] ));
    char *sep = "";
    /**
     * strtok modifies the input string by overwriting the delimiter with
     * the 0 string terminator; to preserve the contents of words[random],
     * we need to copy it to a temporary string, and call strtok on that
     * copy.
     */
    char temp[20];                  
    strcpy( temp, words[random] );  
    token = strtok( temp, search ); 
    while(token!=NULL)              
    {
      printf("%s\"%s\"",sep, token);
      sep = ", ";
      token = strtok(NULL, search);
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
0:             " c a r ", len is  7: token list:  "c", "a", "r"
1:       " b e a t l e ", len is 13: token list:  "b", "e", "a", "t", "l", "e"
2:           " b e a r ", len is  9: token list:  "b", "e", "a", "r"
3:             " c a t ", len is  7: token list:  "c", "a", "t"
```

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish with `list` and `matrix`, but this should at least help clear up any issues you're having with tokenizing the strings.

Comment: strlen still gives 2 each time :((